# Prove the NP-hardness of the following problem: Whether there exists a partition for a set of data points

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity, np

Can anybody help me prove the NP-hardness of the following question:
Given $x_0, x_1, ..., x_m \in \mathbb{R}^n$, determine whether there exists a partition $S\cup [m]\backslash S$, such that $x_0 \in conv(\{x_i|i\in S\})$ and $x_0 \in conv(\{x_i|i\in[m]\backslash S\})$?

Comment: I'm having trouble with your notation.  
1) If this is a computational decision problem, what do you mean by input size if the vectors are real-valued?
2) What do you mean by $[m]$?  If [m] means $\{1,\ldots,m\}$ I suggest using another notation for $x_0$ seeing as it has a completely different role in the story.
3) I'm guessing that conv mean convex hull?

Comment: For fixed n it is polynomial in m. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_theorem_(convex_hull)

Comment: I should be clearer. $x_0, x_1, ..., x_m \in \mathbb{Q}^n$, and $[m] = \{1,...,m\}$. $conv(\cdot)$ means the convex hull of the input. Both $n, m$ are not fixed.

Comment: Thought: Is the problem any easier if $x_1,\ldots,x_m\in \{0.1\}^n$?  That has a more combinatorial flavor.  Maybe that's already NP-hard, and maybe still if you assume $x_0=(1/2,1/2,\ldots)$.

Comment: Thought: Your question implicitly defines a polyhedral complex, call it, say, the disjoint-reasons hull, so all  the points in the convex hull for disjoint reasons.  It's the union of a lot of intersections of simplexes. A related but purely geometrical question would ask how complicated this complex get (number of vertices, edges, etc.)

Comment: Thanks, that helps! I ll think about if we restrict $x_j$ to be binary!